# How do you do a "through" join with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, associations

I have 3 tables: `events`, `event_groups`, and `calendars`. `calendars` has *many* `event_groups` and `events` has *one* `event_group` and calendars and events are associated through event_groups.

I'm trying to wrap my head around how I write like:

```
SELECT * FROM event_groups WHERE calendar = 1;
SELECT * FROM events WHERE events_groups = "all event group IDs from previous"
```

For visualization purposes, here's how the data would ideally come out in a REST service

```
{
  calendar: {
    event_groups: [
      {
        name: "Federal Holidays",
        events: [
          { ... },
          { ... },
          { ... }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Personal Schedule",
        events: [
          { ... },
          { ... },
          { ... }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What are your primary and foreign key columns?

Comment: SELECT e.* FROM events e INNER JOIN event_groups eg ON e.event_groupid = eg.id WHERE eg.calendar_id = 1

Comment: @HannoBinder primary is always `id` and then foreign would be `calendar_id` for event_groups and `event_group_id` for events.